# How to show "No results" message using list search filter?

Tags: javascript

How to display the "no results" message correctly when there's no matches found on the list? when i type in the input doesn't' work correctly.

The message appears even with results during the search.

```js
function search() {

  input = document.querySelector("#input_search")

  filter = input.value.toUpperCase()

  list_items = document.querySelectorAll("li")
  list_items.forEach(item => {

    a = item.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

    txt = a.textContent || a.innerText;

    if (txt.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      item.style.display = "";
    } else {
      item.style.display = "none";
    }


    if (window.getComputedStyle(item, null).getPropertyValue("display") == 'none') {
      document.querySelector(".no-result").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.querySelector(".no-result").style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
}

document.querySelector("#input_search").addEventListener('input', () => search())
```

```html
<input type="search" id="input_search" placeholder="Search">

<ul id="list">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="no-result" style="display: none;">No results</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change up how you deal with showing and hiding elements. A helper class, such as `.hidden`, can be very helpful, and allows you to use the built in [`Element.prototype.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) object, which has some helpful things in it. I've tried to comment the code as best as I can to explain what I've changed, but comment if you have any questions.

```js
function search() {
  // When bound with the event listener, "this" becomes the object the event listener is on.
  input = this;

  filter = input.value.toUpperCase()
  // we want to make sure we are only getting LI elements from inside our specific list.
  list_items = document.querySelectorAll("#list li");
  // not a lone of reason to use forEach anymore, when for(let item of list_items){...} would do the same thing.
  list_items.forEach(item => {
    // the previous way of using the tagname etc was functionally the same to this.
    a = item.querySelector("a");
    txt = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    // This has a similar feature to jQuery's class toggle.
    // If the portion in the second argument evaluates to true, the class will be applied.
    // Otherwise, the class is not.
    item.classList.toggle('hidden', txt.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == -1);
  });
  // Written this way for readability
  document.querySelector('.no-result').classList.toggle(
    'hidden', 
    // If every element from the array contains a hidden, the .every call wil be true.
    // since we want to SHOW the element in that case, we use the opposite to determine if the class should be applied.
    !Array.from(list_items).every(item => item.classList.contains('hidden'))
  );
}
// the whole () => search() thing was redundant. This is just fine.
document.querySelector("#input_search").addEventListener('input', search)
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="input_search" placeholder="Search">

<ul id="list">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="no-result hidden">No results</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have a flag outside of your `forEach`, that you toggle to `true` on the first result found matching - and then set the display of your `No result` message based on this

Currently, you're checkng for displaying the `No result` message after every loop, which is why you're getting wrong values

```js
function search() {
  let match = false;
  input = document.querySelector("#input_search")

  filter = input.value.toUpperCase()

  list_items = document.querySelectorAll("li")
  list_items.forEach(item => {

    a = item.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

    txt = a.textContent || a.innerText;

    if (txt.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      match = true
      item.style.display = "";
    } else {
      item.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
  
  if (match === false) {
    document.querySelector(".no-result").style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".no-result").style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.querySelector("#input_search").addEventListener('input', () => search())
```

```html
<input type="search" id="input_search" placeholder="Search">

<ul id="list">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="no-result" style="display: none;">No results</div>
```

However, there's a few things in your code I think you could improve - I've added this as another Snippet if you want to see; I've commented the main changes

```js
function search() {
  // 'let' to define your variables in the currect scope
  let input = document.querySelector("#input_search");
  let list_items = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  let filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  
  let match = false;
  
  list_items.forEach(item => {
    // No reason to target `a` elements, or to check .innerText - .textContent will handle it
    // Might as well .toUpperCase() as you get the value
    let text = item.textContent.toUpperCase();
    
    // ES6 includes because it's cleaner ( personally )
    if (text.includes(filter)) {
      match = true;
      item.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
  
  // Can use a terniary operator for a single line if / else
  document.querySelector(".no-result").style.display = match ? 'none' : 'block';
}

document.querySelector("#input_search").addEventListener('input', () => search())
```

```html
<input type="search" id="input_search" placeholder="Search">

<ul id="list">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="no-result" style="display: none;">No results</div>
```